# android Responsive design VS CSS Resposnive Design

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I wanna make android application with responsive design concept.
After searching and searching, I found that there are two ways for doing that :

- By adding new xml files under res folder like layout-sw800dp/activity1.xml and values-sw800dp/activity1.xml , and android detects the screen size during run time and loads the appropriate xml file.
- By making CSS responsive design and loading it in android but I don't know how to deal with buttons' actions in this way.

I ask about the best way for doing responsive design in android and what are the advantage and disadvantages for each way and how to deal with the buttons in the second way ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @schabluk. Android provides RelativeLayout which is similar to responsive design in html.

Your first way of creating layout is not appropriate as there are thousands of android mobiles.

Use android's  [Webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) for handling button events. Webview is a view for embedding html content in android applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow "Best Practices for User Experience & UI". See [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) tutorial.